# Ask delete confirmation only on last row

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets, delete-row

In my JSF application I have to delete rows from an employee table with other details. I am able to delete rows in the view, but I want to have a delete confirmation dialogue only on the last row deletion.

I have implemented it using JavaScript, but it pops up for every delete.

Now, I want it only for last row, I can check if it is last row through managed bean, but how this can be implemented in the view?

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the table in the view you could use your `js` to check if there is only 1 row in the table when you click the delete button or however your deleting.

To do this you will need your html elements to have meaninful names, you can achieve this in jsf by using the `id` attribute in your view. You can then find the table `$(#table-id)` and see how many rows it has.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.rows) property of the HTML DOM `<table>` element to get all rows as an array on which you can invoke the `length` property to know about the length.

So, all with all, this should do:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:dataTable id="table" ...>
        <h:column>
            <h:commandButton value="delete" ...
                onclick="if (document.getElementById('form:table').rows.length == 1) return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in your managed bean class before delete logic check table size.

```
  if(table.size == 1){
    popup = true;
   }
```

write another action that will called when Popups OK button clicked.